# Wait stored procedure execution until previous execution completes in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to execute a stored procedure in every 30 seconds. I register a method in `Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` to run in every 30 seconds. This stored procedure takes long time to execute. The issue is whether the previous execution is completed or not the next iteration tries to execute the sp again. This causes some time out issues.

Is there any way to wait for the previous execution get completed before executing the next iteration in sql server?

Comment: why are you doing this?  What problem are you trying to solve?  There may be a better way.  An additional question - going to be wordy sorry.  Say the proc takes 1.5 minutes to execute.  If after 2 minutes (30 seconds past the completion of the proc) is the proc supposed to only run once more at that 30 second mark?  Or should the proc be queued the 2-3 additional times for the 30 seconds that passed during the 1.5 minute execution?

Comment: @Kritner, I have a category which has lot of users with different permissions. When some thing got changed in the category i need to re-publish all the items to the relevant users. To cater that i'm doing this operation.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use Sql Agent for such occasions.  It will do what you want automatically.

If thats not an option you could use a semaphore flag.  The first thing the SP does is check a table / field for a 1 for in process.  If it is 0 then the SP updates to 1, if it is already 1 then the SP exits.  At the end of the SP it gets set back to 0.

Comment: Did you mean creating a sql sever job scheduling task for this?

Comment: @Aruna - Yes, that's exactly what he means. Should solve your problem. SQL Server Agent won't start a new run if he notices the previous run is still going. However, if your procedure runs that long, and you need to execute it every 30 seconds, I would start looking into optimizing that..

Comment: Yes. Agree with jens. That bulk publishing wont happen very frequently  but the other logics will. When all come together, then it thtows time out.